# express app get pattern is throwing "Cannot GET"

Tags: node.js, regex, typescript, express

I have the following type of pages:

1. root (`/`)
2. todays chapter (`/929` OR `/929/`) which eventually redirects to `/929/<CHAPTER>` where `<CHAPTER>` is a natural number between 1 to 929
3. chapters (`/929/<CHAPTER>` OR `/929/<CHAPTER>/`) where `<CHAPTER>` is a natural number between 1 to 929
4. articles about the chapters (`/929/<CHAPTER>/<ARTICLE_ID>` OR `/929/<CHAPTER>/<ARTICLE_ID>/`), where `<CHAPTER>` is a natural number between 1 to 929 and  is a natural number like 1,2...99999999

1 to 3 page types work fine. The fourth is throwing:

> Cannot GET /929/233/3027

Here's code:

```
app.get("/", rootMiddleware);
app.get("/929[/]{0,1}", todaysChapterMiddleware);
app.get("/929/:chapter(([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-8][0-9]{2}|9[01][0-9]|92[0-9]))[/]{0,1}", chapterMiddleware);
app.get("/929/:chapter(([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-8][0-9]{2}|9[01][0-9]|92[0-9]))/:articleId((\d+))[/]{0,1}", articleMiddleware);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the regular expression is usually part of a literal string, be sure to escape any \ characters with an additional backslash, for example \\d+.

So the correct fourth route should be:

```
app.get("/929/:chapter(([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-8][0-9]{2}|9[01][0-9]|92[0-9]))/:articleId((\\d+))[/]{0,1}", articleMiddleware);
```

Answer (score 1):

add \ to escape the \

so

from

```
app.get("/929/:chapter(([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-8][0-9]{2}|9[01][0-9]|92[0-9]))/:articleId((\d+))[/]{0,1}", articleMiddleware);
```

to

```
app.get("/929/:chapter(([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-8][0-9]{2}|9[01][0-9]|92[0-9]))/:articleId((\\d+))[/]{0,1}", articleMiddleware);
```

Answer (score -1):

In app.js main file:

```
app.use("/",routesfile);
```

In routes file:

```
router.get('/929/<CHAPTER>',controller file)
```